# Having problems with Deleting using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using the udemy course for mongoose and it's outdated. I don't know to get the latest format for using Mongoose

I tried to delete a list item from a list I created but it doesn't work. When I wrapped it in an if statement it just keeps loading in my browser and nothing happens.

Comment: You need to provide some code for someone to be able to help. Edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.